# Launch IE browser in JAVA and using POST method

Tags: java, internet-explorer, post, awt

We have a Java awt desktop application on Windows machine. We have provided a button with hyperlink to third party web based application .
Click on button should do following :

1. Launch new instance of Internet Explorer on the machine.
2. Open the URL of third party application in IE
3. Submit few parameters and their values using http "POST" method in IE.

It will open the application in Browser and user will work in new Window with no further interaction with Java application.

We are able to achieve this using java.awt.Desktop.browser in "GET" method . But due to security restrictions we are not supposed to pass these parameters using GET method as they are visible in URL.

I have received some suggestions to do this by using intermediate vbscript but can it be achieved within Java .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly I cannot help you with invoking IE with POST and to be honnest not sure if it is even possible via vbscript. But if you have some vbscript capable of doing such thing, you can allways invoke it from java see commons-exec library. By platform invoke you can also invoke any platform special stuff - see JNA in https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

But maybe another approach - why not use encryption and hmac verification of your parameters ? When you carefully use them, you can use GET also.

Comment: GET has limit for parameters passed. I am stuck with similar situation where I have data with unknown size and a url. Please let me know if it can be done using POST.

Comment: @akash That is true, GET has limits. From Java you can invoke POST using for example Apache HttpComponents or by using other ways. But what I do not know if it is even possible to invoke IE with POST. Personally I think no and I would choose another integration pattern. For example to call POST and transfer data, third party application will return unique URL. Than you can invoke IE via GET on such URL.